# Look for last column that has a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file with 8+ "Sales" columns spreading throughout my worksheet. I tried the following code to do: If any Sales cells have "Title Transfer" then the 51st column would have an "x".

```
Option Explicit
Public Const colTTransfer As Long = 51

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim counter As Long

lastColumn = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If Me.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = "Sales" Then

        For counter = 1 To lastColumn

            If Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value = "Title Transfer" Then

            Me.Cells(Target.Row, colTTransfer).Value = "x"

            End If

        Next counter

    End If

End Sub
```

However, I realised there was more to my original purpose and the above codes weren't flexible. My codes check any Sales cells that are `Title Transfer` but they didn't reflect the changes of other Sales cells within the same rows.

For example, if a cell in my 1st Sales column has `Title Transfer` then the 51st column would return an `x`. And if the cell in the 2nd Sales column within the same row has a different value, e.g. `Green`, the `x` in the 51st column should be removed (which my codes can't)

So I'm wondering if there is a way to only return `x` for the **last** Sales column that has `Title Transfer`?

For example, assuming these events happen in the same row where:

- 1st Sales column has `Green` and 51st column remain blank
- 2nd Sales column has `Title Transfer` and 51st column has `x`
- 3rd Sales column has `Rollup` and 51st column turns blank
- 4th Sales column has `Red` and 51st column remains the same
- 5th Sales column has `Title Transfer` and 51st column now has `x`
  and so on

This what my data looks like:

```html
| Title  | Engine   Family  | Market Segment | Customer | Engine Model | S/N | Build Spec | ACTL.FINISH | Sales Order | Item  | Committed Date | EPS Date   | Target | Sales | Production | Day 1 | Status | Sales          | Production | Day 2 | Status | Sales  | Production | Day 3 | Status | Sales | Production | Day 4 | Status | Sales          | Production | Day 5 | Status | Sales  | Production | Day 6 | Status | Sales          | Production | Day 7 | Status | Sales | Production | Day 8 | Status | Status | Comments | MB51 Shipped | FPS? | Plant | Title Transfer |
|--------|------------------|----------------|----------|--------------|-----|------------|-------------|-------------|-------|----------------|------------|--------|-------|------------|-------|--------|----------------|------------|-------|--------|--------|------------|-------|--------|-------|------------|-------|--------|----------------|------------|-------|--------|--------|------------|-------|--------|----------------|------------|-------|--------|-------|------------|-------|--------|--------|----------|--------------|------|-------|----------------|
| Rollup | PS               | APU            | HAC      | T-62T-46C12  | 1   | BS1        | 0000-00-00  | 0           | 0     | 2019/12/31     | 2019/12/31 |        | Green |            |       |        | Title Transfer |            |       |        | Rollup |            |       |        | Red   |            |       |        | Title Transfer |            |       |        | Rollup |            |       |        | Title Transfer |            |       |        |       |            |       |        |        |          |              |      |       |  x             |
|        |                  |                |          |              |     |            |             |             |       |                |            |        |       |            |       |        |                |            |       |        |        |            |       |        |       |            |       |        |                |            |       |        |        |            |       |        |                |            |       |        |       |            |       |        |        |          |              |      |       |                |
|        |                  |                |          |              |     |            |             |             |       |                |            |        |       |            |       |        |                |            |       |        |        |            |       |        |       |            |       |        |                |            |       |        |        |            |       |        |                |            |       |        |       |            |       |        |        |          |              |      |       |                |
```

[Link to sample](https://liveconcordia-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/t_oa_live_concordia_ca/EY_L1t-HbtpOph2e6ontOYYB2NhpF2x5kEVbokipvSNb9w?e=guxsGv)

Please advise how I can make it work that way. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60440086/edit) to include sample data and desired outcome?

Comment: You will need to show more than one row to demonstrate your issue... Show some sample data that clearly shows the issue you are trying to solve for. Seeing the problem in action will likely make it easier to debug.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad my apologies, I've added the data in my post. The desired outcome was written in those bullet points you saw in the post as well. Thanks

Comment: @urdearboy Sorry my issue concerns row level I believe, and I really don't know how I can reflect that with more rows. I've explained in the post under those bullet points

Comment: "1st Sales column has Green" --> I see no "Green" in your sample row... Same with "Title Transfer" and "Red". hence the need for more rows. [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad 1st Sales column is column N which has Green as I see. It's the column after `Target` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. Still, thank you for everyone's help

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim r As Range, r1 As Range, lastColumn As Long, counter As Long
  Dim MaxCol As Variant, rg As Range, j As Long

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:AP")) Is Nothing And Target.Column Mod 4 = 2 Then
    Set r = Intersect(Target, Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion, Columns(Target.Column).Resize(, 3))
    Call DoCells(r)
  End If

  ' Get last column based on first row
  lastColumn = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  If Me.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = "MB51 Shipped" Then
    For counter = 1 To lastColumn
      If (Me.Cells(1, counter).Value = "Sales" Or Me.Cells(1, counter).Value = "Production") And IsEmpty(Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value) Then
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value = "Rollup"
      End If
    Next counter
  End If

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:AP")) Is Nothing And Target.Column Mod 4 = 2 Then
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set rg = Range("N" & Target.Row & ":AP" & Target.Row)
    MaxCol = 0
    For j = Columns("AP").Column To Columns("N").Column Step -4
      If Cells(Target.Row, j) <> "" Then
        If j > MaxCol Then MaxCol = j
      End If
    Next
    If MaxCol Mod 4 = 2 Then
      If Cells(Target.Row, MaxCol).Value = "Title Transfer" Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 51).Value = "x"
      Else
        Cells(Target.Row, 51).Value = ""
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the Title Transfer field update to the end of the loop and evaluate each Sales column to the end. The updated code should resolve that.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column < colTTransfer Then
        If Trim(UCase(Me.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value)) = "SALES" Then
            Dim lastColumn As Long
            Dim counter As Long
            Dim rowIsTitleTransfer As Boolean

            lastColumn = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            rowIsTitleTransfer = False

            ' loop
            For counter = 1 To lastColumn
                If Trim(UCase(Me.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value)) = "SALES" Then
                    rowIsTitleTransfer = Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value = "Title Transfer"
                End If
            Next counter

            ' assign title transfer column
            If rowIsTitleTransfer Then
                Me.Cells(Target.Row, colTTransfer).Value = "x"
            Else
                Me.Cells(Target.Row, colTTransfer).Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the codes. I put them exactly as you rewrote but the 51st column remained blank even when I put "Title Transfer". Do you know why?

Comment: It looks like your existing code is expecting a user to click on one of the "Sales" columns or else it won't trigger. Was that by design and did you click on one of the sales columns to trigger it when you tested?

Comment: Hi, yes to what you asked. My team would manually enter values for those Sales column and therefore I had to make the event happen/update whenever a Sales cell changes

Comment: Caught the mistake. Updated.

Comment: Sorry to tell you again but it didn't work. I've included a link to the sample file. At this point, I really don't know what's going on with my file. The codes should be in "Master Worksheet"

Comment: I've found a couple bugs with the code that I updated, but I doubt the posted code fixed the issue you are seeing. The `Sub` as posted will work, but you should double check your assumptions about columns and rows -- I found an issue that I want you to find.